# Different Form Views for Different groups

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, infopath

I'm creating a Help Desk in Sharepoint.

I want users with a certain role (owners) to be able to edit any field on a ticket after it's been submitted. Other users should not be able to edit any fields, but they should be able to add comments.

I've already added a view to the form in InfoPath. I've also added/edited Web Parts on the form to make two new versions:

1) Help Desk View (all fields editable) -- with target group HD Owners
2) Submit Comment View (only can add comments) -- with target groups HD Contributors and HD Visitors
3) The standard view of the form. This form is hidden in the Layout control of the Web Part configurator.

The issue that I'm running into is that form views 1 and 2 are showing up blank on Edit mode. I can't get the data to populate in the ticket when it's loaded. The data still shows up in view 3 when I make it not hidden, but that's obviously not what I'm going for.

Any thoughts on how to make the data populate on these other Web Parts forms that I've added?

Edit: I've gotten rid of view 2, and set those groups as the target groups on view 3. However, view 3 is still not populating any data at all.

Edit 2: I'm using Forms > InfoPath Form Web Part. Is there a different Web Part I should be using?

Edit 3: Also, I'm using [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/39ee13ae-eaa3-4926-a915-51a8f64d9ca4/how-to-customize-list-form-views-for-different-user-types?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) answer as the basis of what I'm doing--I can feel that I'm close, but just not sure what I'm missing.

Edit 4: I've been trying to use [this]-- (Link removed--I don't have enough imaginary internet points to post more than 2 links) site to work it out. It looks like I'm close, but when I try to use the GetUserCollectionByGroup query fields, it shows them as blank in preview mode, and when I use the data fields, it shows the login info of the user who owns the group.

Edit 5: [This site](https://web.archive.org/web/20151017091041/http://info.akgroup.com:80/blog-0/bid/69277/InfoPath-Restrict-visibility-to-users-in-a-SharePoint-Group) was the same info as in Edit 4, but it was slightly easier to use (and I didn't have to modify his code to make it work). I'm still having an issue with the information he provided -- it's still showing me the info of the owner of the group for some reason.

Edit 6: Alright, after 6 hours of work, I think I'm back at square 1. It won't let the form upload, or doesn't let me use the data connection, or something. Not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured out a workaround. The issue is that I don't have authorizations to the SOAP connections on the site:

1. I created a new list called "HD Users," and added the users that were in the HD Sharepoint Group to the list. It had one field beyond the standard, and that was "Person/Group" and was limited to users in the HD group that I mentioned.
2. In the form, I created a new field. I think it's actually called "test2" although something like "Help Desk Employee ID" would probably have been more accurate.
3. I also created a new data connection tied to the list. I made sure that I imported the "UserID" field in addition to the standard ID field.
4. In the form view that was for the end user, I added test2 to the window, and gave it a default value that looked like this:

`AccountID[translate(substring-after(.,"|"),"abc...","ABC...") = translate(substring-after(userName(),"|"),"abc...","ABC...")]`

5. (Obviously, there are probably better ways to write that code, but at this point, it's working and I ain't messing with it until it breaks).
6. Added a Form Load rule that says "If test2 = userName() then change to view"

There are always going to be more steps than I can list here, but if anyone runs into this issue and doesn't have access to the SOAP data connections that are so often suggested, I'd be happy to help out and give more detail if necessary.